# Is react native modules sending events to javascript doc correct?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, facebook, react-native

In facebook's [doc](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html#content) it says

```
- (void)calendarEventReminderReceived:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSString *eventName = notification.userInfo[@"name"];
    [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName:@"EventReminder"
                                               body:@{@"name": eventName}];
}
```

JavaScript code can subscribe to these events:

```
var subscription = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
    'EventReminder',
    (reminder) => console.log(reminder.name)
);
```

But I can never get this work. Should this be sendDeviceEventWithName instead? Also should native module always be singleton?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, no. Please see this issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/394

> Changing the example Objective-C to call sendDeviceEventWithName
>   instead of sendAppEventWithName fixes the problem.

This seems to confirm what you've suggested. There's a pull request waiting to be merged for this:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/530

Comment: Cool, Thanks. It seems to be working fine after I change to sendDeviceEventWithName.

Comment: I can't actually get this to work myself! Any chance you could post your (simplified) code somewhere please?

Comment: The trick is to  make your natvie module a singleton. Just check _bridge in your  instance and make sure it is not nil. I'm not sure this is a feature or a bug though.

Comment: Yeah _bridge was nil when I tried - how do you go about making it a singleton though?

Comment: `@implementation NativeEventBridge

    @synthesize bridge = _bridge;

    + (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
    {
      static NativeEventBridge *sharedInstance = nil;
      static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
      dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
      });
      return sharedInstance;
    }

    @end`

Comment: The answer is from April but apparently this is still the case?? I just wasted three hours trying to get the code from the docs to work :(

Comment: It actually works both ways now, I just tested it but you need to add the listener on the right emitter (NativeAppEventEmitter/DeviceEventEmitter). The docs are wrong, just in a different way :)

Comment: I am also following the same code and after a long struggle, the code was run without any errors. But when I show the subscription  in an alert in js code it doesn't showing the value. Here we are not calling the function calendarEventReminderReceived. How can we get the subscription value..